# Reading html from a html file and displaying it in a view through Java MVC

Tags: java, spring-mvc

I understand displaying html files through MVC is not straight forward as jsps are used as the main views.

I've got as far as reading in the html file in the controller and adding the string to the model and view.

(Controller code)

```
String content = getStringOfFile(myHtmlFile.html);

ModelAndView mv = new ModelAndView("jspPage");
mv.addObject("content", content);
```

In the jsp I've used a  tag to display the content of the string attached to the model and view object.

(jsp page)

```
<c:out value="${content}"/>
```

(current undesired output)

```
<html><body><p>Another test page 2</p></body></html>
```

the content is displayed, however it includes all of the tags that I wouldn't expect a jsp to render. Is there another way I can dynamically add the string to the jsp where the tags will be ignored when displaying in the browser?

Comment: Couldn't you just `jsp:include` your file in the page?

Comment: The html page loaded will depend on what 'object' has been selected. Each 'object' has its own html page which I determine the name of at run time. Is it possible to add the html page to the model and view and then provide that to the jsp:include?

Answer (score 0):

escapeXml attribute did the trick:

```
<c:out value="${content}" escapeXml="false"/>
```